# How can i echo total of both variables as expected?

Tags: php

I wrote a simple script for echoing total of two variables to `<h1>` tag, but it gives strange results

```
<?php

    $i=10; $j=20;

    var_dump($i);
    var_dump($j);
    echo '<h1>'.$i+$j.'</h1>';

?>
```

Result of this script:

```
int(10)
int(20)
20</h1>
```

I was expecting 30 but it ate up `<h1>` tag, how  can i do this as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`echo '<h1>'.($i+$j).'</h1>';`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574624/arithmetic-operation-within-string-concatenation-without-parenthesis-causes-stra) explains why you need to concatenate like this. [Here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#Id7pcFbEl) is a working demo.

Comment: yes, but can you explain, what is happening without braces ?

Comment: Priority of operators

Comment: It's a [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) thing.